# How do I answer 这是哪儿?

Tags: meaning

I'm confused about answering 这是哪儿. Should I answer directly and say that this is a restaurant, or if I should give a general answer and say this is Utica, if someone asks me that question？

Comment: It depends on the context.

Comment: If you are at the Denny's off the I-90 interchange, say "Utica."  If you are in a small restaurant downtown, give the street address -- it may help if you can point to it printed on the menu or somewhere.  If you are at the famous restaurant Tailor and The Cook, then by all means say proudly Tailor and The Cook!  If the person meant something else, give them a moment to clarify their question.

Answer (score 2):

It really should depend on the context. Note that "Where am I?" has similar ambiguity in English.

For instance, if I'm at a shop and speaking to someone on the phone who wants to know where I am, and I ask the shopkeeper 这是哪里？, it's expected for the name of the shop (or its location) to be given. This might also hold if I am on the street.

Comparatively, in some cases, I might want less specific information. If someone is bringing me into an unfamiliar store, I might instead expect the answer to indicate what *type* of store I am in. If I have been driving long distances and have just stopped, I *might* expect 这是哪里？ (if asked by a passenger I am carrying) to be about what town I am in, not what road I am on.

Comment: Just in case OP is starting out learning: 哪里 is equivalent to 哪儿 (哪儿 is more Northern feeling)

Comment: @赵永ChrisDown: oops, I didn't notice I'd changed the word. Thanks for the clarifying comment.